# Dynamic SQL getting cutoff despite being nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

```
declare @sql6 nvarchar(max) = ''

set @sql6 = @sql6 + ' CODE'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL6
```

Is there any case where declaring a dynamic SQL in this way could get cut off?

It is a bunch of code, dont want to paste a wall of text, but the print statement ends with:

```
GROUP BY 
    T1.TreatmentID, T1.SamplingRandomNumber,
    T1.ProductID, T1.OptimizationGroupID,
    T1.CurrencyCode, C.CalculatedFromText,
    T1.TreatmentOrdinal, T1.SourceCode,
    T1.[IsPriorBoo
```

where it should be a bunch more.

The error is

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Full code of the particular part of the query (inside a large dynamic query)

```
SELECT 
    T1.TreatmentID,
    T1.SamplingRandomNumber,
    T1.ProductID, 
    T1.OptimizationGroupID,
    T1.CurrencyCode,
    C.CalculatedFromText,
    CONVERT(FLOAT,COUNT(1)) CountCalculatedFromText,
    T1.TreatmentOrdinal,
    Sum(T1.Revenue) AS Revenue,
    T1.SourceCode
    '+replace(@ColumnsPB,'t.','T1.') +'
INTO 
    #RevenueDetailCount 
FROM 
    #RevenueDetailCountTmp T1
INNER JOIN 
    #CalculatedFromText C ON  T1.ProductID = C.ProductID 
                          AND T1.OptimizationGroupID = C.OptimizationGroupID
                          AND T1.TreatmentOrdinal = C.TreatmentOrdinal
                          AND T1.SamplingRandomNumber = C.SamplingRandomNumber
GROUP BY 
    T1.TreatmentID,
    T1.SamplingRandomNumber,
    T1.ProductID, 
    T1.OptimizationGroupID,
    T1.CurrencyCode,
    C.CalculatedFromText,
    T1.TreatmentOrdinal,
    T1.SourceCode
     '+replace(@ColumnsPB,'t.','T1.') +'
```

Edit:
full printed dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @CalculatedFromText AS TABLE
(
    CalculatedFromText varchar(100), 
    CalculatedFrom     smallint
)

INSERT INTO @CalculatedFromText 
( 
    CalculatedFromText, 
    CalculatedFrom
)
VALUES 
    ('Control' ,1), 
    ('Treatment' ,2), 
    ('Dynamic' ,3)




select 
    TP.TreatmentID,
    TP.ProductID,
    TP.OptimizationGroupID,
    MIN(TP.CalculatedFromText) AS CalculatedFromText,
    TP.TreatmentOrdinal,
    TP.SamplingRandomNumber,
    TP.CurrencyCode,
    TP.SourceCode
    , TP.[IsPriorBooking]
INTO #CalculatedFromText
FROM #CalculatedFromTextTmp TP
GROUP BY  
    TP.TreatmentID,
    TP.ProductID, 
    TP.OptimizationGroupID,
    TP.TreatmentOrdinal,
    TP.SamplingRandomNumber,    
    TP.CurrencyCode ,
    TP.SourceCode
    , TP.[IsPriorBooking]



SELECT  
    SamplingRandomNumber,
    TreatmentID,
    CalculatedFromText, 
    ProductID, 
    OptimizationGroupID,
    CONVERT(FLOAT,COUNT(1)) AS CountCalculatedFromText,
    TreatmentOrdinal,
    CurrencyCode,

    SourceCode
    , [IsPriorBooking]
INTO #CountCalculatedFromText
FROM #CalculatedFromText
GROUP BY
    SamplingRandomNumber,
        TreatmentID, 
        CalculatedFromText,
         ProductID,
         OptimizationGroupID,
         TreatmentOrdinal,
         CurrencyCode,
         SourceCode
         , [IsPriorBooking]
 SELECT 
    SamplingRandomNumber,
    TreatmentID,
    ProductID, 
    OptimizationGroupID,
    SUM(CountCalculatedFromText) AS AllCalculatedFromText,
    CurrencyCode,

    SourceCode
    , [IsPriorBooking]
INTO #AllCalculatedFromText
FROM #CountCalculatedFromText AS cps2
GROUP BY 
    SamplingRandomNumber,
    TreatmentID,
    ProductID,
    OptimizationGroupID,
    CurrencyCode,
    SourceCode
     , [IsPriorBooking]


SELECT 
    CPS.SamplingRandomNumber,
    CPS.TreatmentID,
    CPS.CalculatedFromText, 
    CPS.TreatmentOrdinal,
    CPS.ProductID, 
    CPS.OptimizationGroupID,
    CPS.CountCalculatedFromText,
    CPS.CountCalculatedFromText/T.AllCalculatedFromText AS PercentCalculatedFromText,
    CPS.CurrencyCode,
    CPS.SourceCode
    , CPS.[IsPriorBooking]
INTO #PercentCalculatedFromText
FROM #CountCalculatedFromText AS CPS
    INNER JOIN #AllCalculatedFromText T ON
    T.TreatmentID=CPS.TreatmentID AND T.ProductID = CPS.ProductID
        AND T.OptimizationGroupID = CPS.OptimizationGroupID
        AND T.CurrencyCode = CPS.CurrencyCode

SELECT 
    T.SamplingRandomNumber,
    T.TreatmentID,
    T.ProductID,
    T.OptimizationGroupID,
    T.TreatmentOrdinal,
    T.CurrencyCode, 

    CASE WHEN T.CalculatedFromText = 2 THEN PS.CalculatedFromText + ' + CAST(T.TreatmentOrdinal AS char) 
        ELSE PS.CalculatedFromText END AS PricingType,
    T.CalculatedFromText,
    T.CountCalculatedFromText AS QuantityLooks,
    T.PercentCalculatedFromText  AS LooksPercentageOfTransactions,
    T.SourceCode
    , T.[IsPriorBooking]
INTO #CountCalculatedFromTextPivot
FROM #PercentCalculatedFromText T
    INNER JOIN @CalculatedFromText AS PS ON T.CalculatedFromText = PS.CalculatedFrom



SELECT 
    T1.TreatmentID,
    T1.ProductID, 
    T1.GroupCode,

    T1.OptimizationGroupID,
    CASE WHEN T1.CalculatedFrom = 2 THEN T1.TreatmentOrdinal ELSE 0 END AS TreatmentOrdinal,
    T1.CurrencyCode,
    T1.SamplingRandomNumber,
    T1.Revenue Revenue,
    T1.SourceCode
    , T1.[IsPriorBooking]
INTO #RevenueDetailCountTmp 
FROM #TreatmentDetails T1
WHERE T1.Stage=2

SELECT 
    T1.TreatmentID,
    T1.SamplingRandomNumber,
    T1.ProductID, 
    T1.OptimizationGroupID,
    T1.CurrencyCode,

    C.CalculatedFromText,
    CONVERT(FLOAT,COUNT(1)) CountCalculatedFromText,
    T1.TreatmentOrdinal,
    Sum(T1.Revenue) AS Revenue,
    T1.SourceCode
    , T1.[IsPriorBooking]
INTO #RevenueDetailCount    
FROM #RevenueDetailCountTmp T1
    INNER JOIN #CalculatedFromText C ON  T1.ProductID = C.ProductID 
        AND T1.OptimizationGroupID = C.OptimizationGroupID
        AND T1.TreatmentOrdinal = C.TreatmentOrdinal
        AND T1.SamplingRandomNumber = C.SamplingRandomNumber
GROUP BY 
    T1.TreatmentID,
    T1.SamplingRandomNumber,
    T1.ProductID, 
    T1.OptimizationGroupID,
    T1.CurrencyCode,
    C.CalculatedFromText,
    T1.TreatmentOrdinal,
    T1.SourceCode
     , T1.[IsPriorBoo
```

Comment: I believe `varchar(max)` tops out at 8000 characters still. Edit: I'm wrong - seems it can be bigger.

Comment: @SeanCoetzee: `varchar(max)` has a capacity of **2 billion** characters (and `nvarchar(max)` has half that, since each character uses 2 bytes)

Comment: nvarchar(max) too? And I had read somewhere as long as I set it to empty string and then add to that string it takes care of a max.

Comment: It is `PRINT` function limit... Instead of print try select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have two issues here. You refer to the PRINT statement - this will stop at 8000 bytes (4000 characters since you're using nvarchar). If you want to show the whole query in SSMS you're best just casting it to XML for output, which will give you a field you can click on in SSMS and display the entire thing.

In the short bit of the query visible, you've actually got an extra quote here in the first part of your THEN which is breaking at least that part of your query:

```
CASE WHEN T.CalculatedFromText = 2 THEN PS.CalculatedFromText + ' + CAST(T.TreatmentOrdinal AS char)
```

Comment: ah makes sense, ill have to do some more testing. thanks